# FlatList overwrite data React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using flatlist to render data from service but it always overwrite list but if i try to display 2 colum it work fine

Code:-

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        const { page, seed } = this.state;
        const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=50`;
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
              error: res.error || null,
              loading: false,
              refreshing: false
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error, loading: false });
          });
};

renderItems = (item) =>  {
        return (<Content>
                  <Text>{item.item.email}</Text>
                </Content>
        );
 }

<FlatList
   data={this.state.data}
   renderItem={this.renderItems}
   keyExtractor={item => item.email}
/>
```

[Error output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj5zw.png)

If i Add numColumns={2} then it will show actual result

```
<FlatList
    numColumns={2}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItems}
    keyExtractor={item => item.email}
/>
```

[Output image with column 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYB1e.png)

Comment: Change `<Content>` to `<View>` and check

Answer (score 2):

The [NativeBase Content](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.7/components#content) component is a wrapper of React Native ScrollView. To avoid this, replace Content with View.